# Show check box as checked using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I already submit a form contain check box value,.for view the form How can I  display the check box as "checked" using angularjs?  I read the value from data source.

Comment: Can you present us with code you have tried?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: A simple google search would have answered you. here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/NW7zk/

Comment: Might wanna look at  : https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{chk}}">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk">
```

in AngularJS

```
$scope.chk = true
```

or

```
$scope.chk = 1
```

that simple

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have data from one or more forms that were submitted and saved already?
And then you want to show the items that have been checked? Or the form with all the items and have the checkboxes that were checked, checked?

For either, it would help to know how the data you are reading is presented. You'll need to get your data from local storage or where ever it was saved. For this example I have it in $scope.model.

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.model = {
     "Item 1":true,
     "Item 2":true,
     "Item 3":false
    };
    
//for the list :
    $scope.checked = []
        for(var i in $scope.model){
            if($scope.model[i]){
                $scope.checked.push(i)
            }
        };
 });
```

```css
body {padding:20px}
div {padding: 10px 0}
p{display: inline}
label {margin-left: 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    <p>Box checked :</p>
    <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="(key, value) in model">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            ng-model="model[key]"/>{{key}}</label>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <p>List of checked item :</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="item in checked">
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```